# How do you auto remove unused imports - Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code to create a game in Unity so I'm programming in C#.  I'd like to know how to:

A) Force the editor to remove unused imports when I save.
B) Remove all unused imports, project-wide

I see allusions to this snippet when I google around:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true
}
```

Neither one does anything for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This worked for me !

- Press `ctrl+ shift+ P`
- Search `settings.json`
- Add the following code

  ```
   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll": true,
    "source.organizeImports": true
  },
  ```

Comment: Are those folder or workspace settings? I added to workspace settings and they do not work =(

Answer (score 5):

This is now natively supported by pylance [as of August 2022](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/python-in-visual-studio-code-august-2022-release/#remove-all-unused-imports), but one needs to explicitly enable the `source.unusedImports` in the `fixAll` list.

It had some performance issues before [yesterday's pre-release](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2023521-10-may-2023-prerelease) (at time of writing) so I recommend installing version `2023.5.21` or above if available.

These are the settings I'm currently using:

```json
  "python.languageServer": "Pylance",
  "python.analysis.fixAll": [
    "source.unusedImports"
  ],
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
```

Before this [I was using](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17463#issuecomment-1093033520) an `autoflake` task along with the [Trigger Task on Save](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.triggertaskonsave) extension. It and similar tasks will result in some "content of the file is newer" complaints but are mostly ok:

```json
// in task.json#tasks
{
  "type": "process",
  "label": "autoflake.removeUnusedImports",
  "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath}",
  "args": [
    "-m",
    "autoflake",
    "-i",
    "--remove-all-unused-imports",
    "${file}"
  ],
  "presentation": {
    "echo": true,
    "reveal": "silent",
    "focus": false,
    "panel": "shared",
    "showReuseMessage": false,
    "clear": false,
    "close": false
  },
  "problemMatcher": []
},
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easily, by pressing the `SHIFT` + `ALT` + `O` on your keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

I use the IntelliJ Keybindings for VSCode as well.
[image: IntelliJ Keybindings]

Once you have it installed, you can use the `Ctrl+Alt+O` to optimize the imports.

Use the shortcut in the file to do for only 1 file. To do it at a directory and all sub-directory level, select the folder from the Project Explorer and then hit the shortcut. It'll optimize the imports for files in all sub-directories.

**Caution**: Updating the keybindings will change the default keybindings of VSCode. Check https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf for details on the IntelliJ Keybindings.

You can use Visual Studio Keybindings if you're familiar with it.
[Visual Studio Keymap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings)

Comment: Ah I don't really want to adopt intellij bindings, I just want to be able to do the cleanup of unused strings.  I'd happily settle for native bindings if I knew what they were...

Comment: Yes, I understand. You can try the Visual Studio keybinding. @Programmer9000

Comment: What are the key bindings to remove unused imports? I use Linux and Shift Alt O doesn't work.