# How to remove all unused imports from a Java file in VS code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code with the Extension Pack for Java.

When I have unused imports like

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
```

in my `.java` file I can remove each import *individually* via the "Quick Fix" action (`Ctrl`+`.`).

But how can I remove *all* unused imports from a Java file in VS Code?

Comment: Take a look at the [link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vs-keybindings) at the end of this answer on another question about using Visual Studio Keybindings for VS code: [How do you auto remove unused imports - Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63312550/1270000)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATA**

Now that vs code **Java** has added a code action, you can use `Remove all unused imports` directly in `quickfix` to remove all unused imports.

[image]

---

You can use the shortcut key <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
. This will format your **import code** and of course remove unused imports.

For example, the original import code is like this

[image]

After using the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to format the import code

[image]

Comment: Currently "Shift+Alt+O" may remove imports that are really used, e.g. "sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameService" in my case.

Comment: @Rom098 - Ermm ... why are you using that class?   Do you realize that it is *internal* and that it is removed (!!!) in Java SE 9?  Methinks that VSCode is doing you a favor by removing it!

Comment: @StephenC I'm fixing JDK8 bugs and creating tests for the fixes. So yes, I completely realize this. It's a pity that VSCode doesn't.

Answer (score 11):

**Fix them on just SAVING the file, the easiest way**

Follow these steps to setup settings in VS Code.

1. Press [Ctrl + , ] to open setting
2. Click on that top-right icon (Open settings JSON) as shown in the below image marked in red.
   [image]
3. Add this below code in settings.json file.

   "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
   "source.organizeImports": true
   }
4. Now just save it and its done

Comment: Make use of the Command Palette for faster access with `Ctrl + Shift + P`. Anyway, thanks for this.